# using a trycatch block to read a csv and an excel file

Tags: r, excel, csv, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to give both options of uploading a csv and an excel sheet in shiny in one function. I am using read.csv to read the csv file and readworksheetfromfile from the XLConnect package to read the excel files. I am using trycatch block for this but I still get errors when the csv file is passed on the readworksheetfromfile function. My tryblock looks like

```
filedata <- reactive({
infile <- input$templatedfile
if (is.null(infile)) {
  # User has not uploaded a file yet
  return(NULL)
} 

importedfile = tryCatch({
  read.csv(infile$datapath,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
},  finally = {
  readWorksheetFromFile(infile$datapath,sheet=1,check.names=FALSE)
})
})
```

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: You might look into **rio** for adaptively reading from a variety of file formats (it uses readxl rather than XLConnect to import Excel files): http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/

Comment: @Thomas, does `rio` get around the current `readxl` issue with `shiny` regarding the file name?  See issue [here](https://github.com/hadley/readxl/issues/85)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would actually be best served implementing a `switch` statement.  That way you don't waste computation time trying to read a file as a csv when it is not.  You also probably want a fall back option in case someone uploads a file that is neither a csv or excel file.  Here is an implementation of your `filedata` function.

```
filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$templatedfile
    if(is.null(infile)){
        return(NULL)
    }
    ext <- file_ext(infile$name)

    importedfile <- 
        switch(ext,
               csv = read.csv(infile$datapath, stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
               xlsx = , xls = readWorksheetFromFile(infile$datapath,
                                                    sheet=1,
                                                    check.names=FALSE),
               stop("file extension not recognized"))
})
```

Here is a simple gist that I used to verify that it works properly.

```
runGist("https://gist.github.com/cdeterman/a41cceadffa7907c505e")
```